# Minimum of $\left\|\begin{pmatrix}\hat{L}-L \\ G\end{pmatrix}\right\|$

Tags: matrices, optimization, normed-spaces

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm invariant under unitary trasformations.

Is it true that

$$\left\|\begin{pmatrix}\hat{L}-L \\ G\end{pmatrix}\right\|$$

is minimized when $\hat{L} = L$ ($\hat{L}$ and $G$ are fixed, $L$ is the only variable quantity), i.e $\left\|\begin{pmatrix}\hat{L}-L \\ G\end{pmatrix}\right\| = \left\|\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ G\end{pmatrix}\right\|$ ?

I'm unable to prove using just elementar inequalities such as triangle inequality or norm properties, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that $\hat L$ is irrelevant for the problem, you can show that using $\min_a \| [a,b]^T \|=\| [0,b]^T \|$ (provided that we can prove it of course).

Comment: @P.Quinton Any idea on how to prove it?

Comment: What are the dimensions of $L,\hat L, G?$ Are they vectors or matrices?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews they are matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the transformation $U$ that maps $[a,b]^T$ into $[-a,b]^T$ is unitary (it might depend on your exact setting), then :
\begin{align*}
\left\| \frac{x+Ux}{2}\right\|&\leq \frac{1}{2}\left( \| x\|+\|Ux\| \right)\\
&= \|x\|
\end{align*}
but if $x=[a,b]^T$ then $\frac{x+Ux}{2}=[0,b]^T$.

Therefore $\min_a \| [a,b]^T \| = \| [0,b]^T \|$. This can then be adapted by translation to your setting.

Comment: Shouldn't be true that the norm is induced by a scalar product in order to use the parallelogram inequality? Here the norm seems just a matricial norm invariant under unitary maps

Comment: Well if the norm is induced by a scalar product then the parallelogram inequality holds, in other cases it could also hold, that is why this is not an answer.

Comment: Using the parallelogram inequality was stupid, instead the same trick with the triangular inequality seems to work, see my edit.